# How to load fonts in rgl.text3d?

Tags: r, rgl

I'm trying to run the example given in `?text3d` as follows:

```
library(rgl)
open3d()
famnum <- rep(1:4, 8)
family <- c("serif", "sans", "mono", "symbol")[famnum]
font <- rep(rep(1:4, each = 4), 2)
cex <- rep(1:2, each = 16)
text3d(font, cex, famnum, text = paste(family, font), adj = 0.5, 
       color = "blue", family = family, font = font, cex = cex)
```

This results in a couple of warning messages of the following kind:

```
In rgl.texts(x = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L,  ... :
  font family "serif" not found, using "bitmap"
```

I would like to use another font instead of bitmap but it seems to switchback to bitmap whatever argument I give as `family` e.g. `family = "FreeSans"`. Wonder if this is a bug or I'm doing something wrong. This is running on

```
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)
with the following rgl version loaded:
[1] rgl_0.96.0
```

Comment: You posted exactly this question on the R-help mailing list, and haven't responded to a question there.  That's rude.

Comment: Indeed I sent the info to both. What's the appropriate way to do this? Provide the link to stackoverflow in the mailing-list? I just responded on the mailing list and haven't responded earlier due to bedtime in these latitudes.

Comment: It's better to ask on just one.  If you don't get an answer there after a day or two, ask on the other.  If you do ask on both, then you should post a summary of the best answer on each to the other one.

Comment: Would be better to post this as a solution and mark it correct. That helps the site and will get you more reputation in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

Solution to the problem is provided by a member in this thread: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2017-March/thread.html#445777

To get this working successfully FreeType and FTGL need to be installed

```
sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev
sudo apt-get install libftgl-dev
```

and then reinstall rgl from within R using

```
install.packages("rgl", type="source")
```